# Flutter - How to make image responsive with all screen sizes

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, responsiveness

Hi I am making a book app in flutter which will have material buttons on top of the image per page. but I notice when I go from iPhone X to iPhone XR or any others, the buttons are all over the place and I see the picture isn't aligned correctly either or same. I need only the landscape mode picture to fill the whole page and be totally responsive on all screens including iPad....
how can I go about doing this..?

I tried media query but when I do screenSizes.width*  any number what's happening is the buttons are not displaying and ... the image is scrolling infinitely and all screen sizes are still showing different images.

I will share my code below for one button and the image

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSizes = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("1 Alif-laam-meem آلم, Pg2")),
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                  // BoxConstraints
                  //   BoxConstraints.expand(
                  // height: 1000,

                  // .expand(
                  width: screenSizes.width * 10,
                  height: screenSizes.height * 10,
                ),

                // children: [
                child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  SafeArea(
                      top: true,
                      bottom: true,
                      right: true,
                      left: true,
                      child: new Container(
                          // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          child: new Image.asset(
                        "test/assets/quranpg0.png",
                        // fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,

                        // color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                        // colorBlendMode:ui.BlendMode.colorDodge,
                      ))),
                  Positioned(
                    // right: 600,

                    bottom: screenSizes.width * 0.985,
                    left: screenSizes.height * 0.87,
                    // bottom: 754.0,
                    // left: 360,
                    // left: width*0.5,
                    // top: 900,
                    // top: 100,
                    child: Opacity(
                      opacity: 0.95,
                      child: _visible
                          ? MaterialButton(
                              // minWidth:screenSize.width*0.1,
                              // 0.1 = 10% of the screen , 0.5 = 50% of the screen
                              // ios sizes usually are 620...
                              // height: screenSize.height*0.1,
                              onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1(),
                              onLongPress: () => changeTextEnglish1(),
                              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
                                // child: Text(labels[i]),
                              ),
                              child: Ink(
                                child: Text(surah0),
                                //  disabledTextColor: Colors.transparent,
//                       color: Colors.cyan[300],
//                       // color: Colors.purple[300],
//                       highlightColor: Colors.blue,
//                       // shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
//                       // ),
//                       textColor: Colors.white,
                                // color: Colors.cyan[400],
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: screenSizes.height * 0.05,
                                    left: screenSizes.width * 0.02,
                                    right: screenSizes.width * 0.02,
                                    bottom: screenSizes.height * 0.05),
                                // EdgeInsets.all(21.0),
                                // left: 28, top: 25, right: 28, bottom: 25),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
// all together looks COOL royal Blue:

                                      Colors.tealAccent[400],
                                      Colors.cyan[900],
                                      Colors.teal

                                      // Color(0xff0E0077),
                                      // Color(0xff1B00EE)
                                    ],
                                    // begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    // end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // color: Colors.blue[300],
                              // highlightColor: Colors.blue,
                              splashColor: Colors.cyan,
                              // ),
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                            )
                          : Container(),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: The page is supposed to adapt to all screens, you have assigned it to the screen of your device that you are testing on only by putting a lot of numbers that I see in the code

Comment: Plea provide a correct code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine the screen orientation, you can do it like so:

```
var orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
```

For a fully working solution that will help you scale elements correctly, I strongly suggest exploring this repo: https://github.com/TechieBlossom/learning_platform_app

There's even a video series with explanations that accompany it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afBmGC63iIQ